# How to setup a autosys job after another job run

Tags: jobs, schedule, autosys

I need one of my autosys job to run after another job.
I setup a condition s(first job name) and set up both at same time.
Second job is running before the first job completes.
How can I make sure the second job runs after the first job.

I dnt want second job to wait until the first job finishes it’s execution and run. I dnt want second job to skip execution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to remove start time from both jobs and put both job in a box.

Secondly, add start time to the box JIL. Hence, once the box starts at the stipulated time, your jobs will get triggered.

Now, based on conditions say for example my first job, which is a FW [fileWatcher] job, will get trigger and be in running state. Whereas the dependent job, LD [loadData] job, will be in activated state, waiting for FW job to complete and send the signal for it to run as file has been successfully received to load the data.

```
start_times: "09:00" #Start time in my box JIL


insert_job: ******_****_***********_LD    job_type: cmd
description: ----------------------------------
machine: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
condition: s(******_****_***********_FW)  #Condition for LD job to wait for FW job to succeed in LD job JIL
```