# Starting an autosys after 30 mins when a job is finished using lookback

Tags: java, scheduler, job-scheduling, autosys, lookback

I need to trigger a autosys job after another job is executed. But this job should only be triggered after 30 Minutes. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987135/how-to-setup-a-autosys-job-after-another-job-run#:%7E:text=First%20of%20all%2C%20you%20need,your%20jobs%20will%20get%20triggered.) but I don't want to create a box. I have setup a lookback condition like this

```
s(job,00.30)
```

Is this an appropriate way to trigger the job?